# GSA search suggest using ss.js or Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, search, google-search-appliance, google-suggest

I'm trying to implement the search suggest for my gsa search box as is described in
http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/612/xml_reference.html#QuerySuggestionServicesuggestProtocol

I was having an issue integrating the javascript file that they mention ss.js as apparently the file is not very lint friendly.

I looked at
http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/gsa-google-search-appliance-suggest-using-c-and-jquery/ and they offer an alternate solution of using a jquery plugin.

I looked around and it doesn't seem like there are too many references to how to implement this ss.js file.  I was wondering if anyone could give me an extra information as to which one might be better to use and why.

This is a .net project using C#.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completing this Question.
You can use Jquery Autocomplete plugin.
All you need to do is pass keyword to this URL 
`http://GSA_HOST/suggest?q=<query>&max=<num>&site=<collection>&client=<frontend>&access=p&format=os`
You will get Different types of JSON response based on format , pick one that is comfortable.
Now in Jquery part

```
$("#search_box_id").autocomplete(
                      "/my_autocomplete_server_side_handler",
                      {
                        minChars:2,
                        loadingClass:"loading",
                        autoFill:true
                      }
            );
```

Some autocomplete plugins require data reponse to be in unique format , like term1|term2|term3 , Check your autocomplete man pages.